# LWC Modal is not fully closing on save

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I've written a LWC to collect some basic information in a modal.  The modal is launched as a quick action from a button on the objects page.  Once the form is completed, and the user saves, the main modal closes, creates the record as it should, shows success with toast.

A couple issues:
1.)  A transparent grey modal still remains and must be manually closed by the user.
2.)  The I have to manually refresh the page to see the newly created object.  Is there a way to force the page to refresh after save to prevent confusion for end users.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjE3j.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGP9s.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1qvv.png)

I have tried modifying the HTML and .JS files to incorporate legacy SLDS methodology (made it worse) and have tried to follow the documentation on the LWC Component Library Reference.

Current relevant JS:

```
    connectedCallback() {
        this.openModal();
    }

    openModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = true;
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }

    handleSave() {
        const fields = {};
        fields[OPPORTUNITY_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.selectedOpportunityId;
        fields[PARTNER_ACCOUNT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.selectedPartnerAccountId;
        fields[CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.selectedCustomerAccountId;
        fields[PARTNER_CONTACT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.selectedPartnerContactId;
        fields[PARTNER_ENGAGEMENT_TYPE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.value;
        fields[CHANNEL_PROGRAM_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.selectedChannelProgramId;

        const recordInput = { apiName: PARTNER_RELATIONSHIP_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
        createRecord(recordInput)
            .then((partnerRelationship) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Partner Relationship created',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.closeModal();
            });
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        this.closeModal();
    }
}
```